# Math.ceil not working with negative floats

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a RoundUp function with help of `Math.ceil` it working fine with positive number but do not round up the negative numbers
Here is what i am trying

```
var value = -12.369754; --> output = -12
// make value = 12.369754; and out put will be 13
var decimalPoints = 0;

if (decimalPoints == 0) {
                value = Math.ceil(parseFloat(value));
            }
console.log(value);
```

Here is the Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/n7ecyr7h/

Why This function?
I need to create a function in which user will give a number and decimal points upto which he wants to round the number The **RoundUp** function will roundUp the given value to a given number of decimal points
For example if user enters `12.12445` and wants to `roundUp to 3 decimal points` the output will be `12.125` 
Here is a table of required outputs with 2 decimal points

```
**Input**              **output**

1.2369                   1.24

1.2869                   1.29

-1.1234                  -1.13

-1.17321                 -1.18
```

And here is the Updated Fiddle with original JS code http://jsfiddle.net/n7ecyr7h/1/

Comment: The output should be -12. It is the value of `-12.369754` rounded **up** (that is, to the nearest whole number towards *positive* infinity). BTW what on Earth is that `decimalPoint` variable and the conditional that makes no sense at all?

Comment: Math.ceil(-12.369754) is -12.
Please check [references](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) at MDN.

Comment: @Powerslave: check the Question, I have explained  it

Comment: 1. Why are you using parseFloat on a float ? That makes no sense. 2. Are you seriously testing each possible value of `decimalPoints` instead of simply doing `* Math.pow(10, decimalPoints)` ?

Comment: @AdilWaqar Well, you gave an example only, not an explanation. And that example could be faulty (you might have been misunderstanding the concept of *rounding up*) as well since you're not rounding *up*, but *away from zero*. `Math.ceil` works as intended. It is just you wanted to do something completely different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Math.ceil` method does actually round up even for negative values. The value `-12` is the closest integer value that is at higher than `-12.369754`.

What you are looking for is to round away from zero:

```
value = value >= 0 ? Math.ceil(value) : Math.floor(value);
```

#### Edit:

To use that with different number of decimal points:

```
// it seems that the value is actually a string
// judging from the parseFloat calls that you have
var value = '-12.369754';
var decimalPoints = 0;

// parse it once
value = parseFloat(value);

// calculate multiplier
var m = Math.pow(10, decimalPoints);

// round the value    
value = (value >= 0 ? Math.ceil(value * m) : Math.floor(value * m)) / m;

console.log(value);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/n7ecyr7h/3/

Comment: please check update in question , I have explained my problem

Comment: @AdilWaqar: I added an example based on your original code above.

Answer (score 1):

Math.ceil(-1.1234) will be -1.12 because in negative -1.12 > -1.1234.
I think you misunderstood mathematically.