# Chrome Returning '-0'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium

In the Chrome JavaScript Console:

`Math.ceil(-0.5)` returns `-0`

`Math.ceil(-0.9)` returns `-0`

`Math.ceil(-0.1)` returns `-0`

**Why is it printing out the negative sign in front of the 0?
I would have expected Chrome to have returned just `0`**

Tested with Chrome (OSX) Version 49.0.2623.110 (64-bit)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Math.ceil not working with negative floats](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26335076/math-ceil-not-working-with-negative-floats)

Comment: It is not a duplicate of that question. That question talks about why negative numbers always round up. This specifically is why 0 has a minus in front of it.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior of `Math.ceil` is defined in the spec at [§ 20.2.2.10](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-math.ceil), with an explicit clause for values between `-1` and `0`:

> If x is less than 0 but greater than -1, the result is −0.

Chrome behaves this way because the spec explicitly requires it and `-0` and `+0` are slightly different.

JavaScript ([§ 6.1.6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type)), and floating point numbers in general ([IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)), make a distinction between positive and negative zero.

The difference is not something you'll run into often, but could be significant (especially when sending data to hardware or within the runtime), so it's not something JS can simply disregard.

Comment: Thank you @ssube for the answer and links to other sources where I can get a more detailed answer